# my splash screen Cause problem in C# winforms

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, splash-screen

In my C# Window Form, the main form (ParentForm) has size equal to 1027, 772
and when I run project everything is fine. but when I add my splash screen form to project. after splash screen run and the parent form is show. The size of the form has been automatically changed and made smaller. In such a way, it does not show half of the controls anymore, and the rest of them are also messed up in size and location. Why does such a problem occur?

the entire of my splash screen code is:

```
 public partial class SplashScreenForm : Form
    {
        public SplashScreenForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            progressBar1.Increment(4);
            if (progressBar1.Value == 100)
            {
                timer1.Enabled = false;
                ParentForm form = new ParentForm();
                form.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }
        }
    }
```

my program.cs code is :

```
  static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new SplashScreenForm());
        }
```

and my parent initialized code is:

```
ManagePageClass MPC = new ManagePageClass();
     public ParentForm()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                MPC.ActivateButton(MainPageBtn, Color.White, downBorderPanel);
                MPC.OpenChildForm(new HomePageForm(), childFormPanel);
            }
```

Comment: You always create new instance of the parent and showing it. Is the original instance closed when spalsh screen appears?

Comment: no. First the splash screen run. then parent form is show. i set the splash screen as start form in programs.cs.

Comment: Have you tried setting the size before showing the parent? e.g `form.Height = 768;`

Comment: no. I changed noting in my parent form properties or in code. when I set parent as start form everything correct. but when I set splash screen the problem showed.

Comment: Do you set specific Height & Width in the form design?

Comment: yes. from preparties is design screen I set the size of splash screen to: 869, 495. parent to: 1005, 621 and all the child docked in the one of panel of parent is: 988, 574

Comment: If the parent size is `1005 x 621` why do you expect it to be `1023,768`?

Comment: sorry i copied wrong. my parent form is: 1027, 772

Comment: Run the `ParentForm`, not the splash Form. In the `Main` and before `.Run(...)`, Create splash instance in `using` block and `.ShowDialog();` it. `.Close();` it when the progress completes. Then, `Application.Run(new ParentForm());`. Also, make sure that your app is Dpi-Aware. Find SO examples on how to enable that if it's not already.

Comment: thanks for all of you both help. I get the idea from your comment. change the autoscclaemode of all form to to Dpi. and now everything is true.